# Proper way of extracting tracer from request Headers for opentelemetry

Tags: go, opentracing, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, krakend

I have krakend apigateway which is using opentracing and sending req headers as X-B3-... for tracing and my service is using opentelemetry. 
This is what I'm having right now on jaeger.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8k7v.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nohj9.png)

I want the service spans to come under  the apigateways'.

**Workaround I have done:**
This is the exact handler for the request using chi router.

```golang
func (env *Env) getCommentForBlogRouter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()

    keys := []string{"X-B3-Traceid", "X-B3-Spanid", "X-B3-Sampled"}
    var carrier propagation.HeaderCarrier = propagation.HeaderCarrier{}
    for _, k := range keys {
        carrier.Set(strings.ToLower(k), r.Header[k][0])
    }

    var propagator propagation.TextMapPropagator = otel.GetTextMapPropagator()
    ctx = propagator.Extract(ctx, carrier)

    // fmt.Println(ctx)
    tr := otel.Tracer("Handler: blog-comments")
    ctx, span := tr.Start(ctx, "handler span")
    defer span.End()

    blogId := r.URL.Query().Get("blog-id")
    span.SetAttributes(attribute.Key("blog-id").String(fmt.Sprint(blogId)))

    var spanDB trace.Span
    ctx, spanDB = tr.Start(ctx, "Select row")

    comments, err := env.comments.GetForBlog(blogId)
    spanDB.End()

    var spanRes trace.Span
    _, spanRes = tr.Start(ctx, "Sending Response")
    defer spanRes.End()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Something went wrong")
        return
    }

    if comments == nil {
        comments = []models.Comment{}
    }
    SendResponse(w, http.StatusOK, map[string]interface{}{
        "data": comments,
    })
}
```

Comment: Don’t post images.

Comment: Okay, will keep in mind. just wanted to share the traces visually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to make it work.
I added this middleware and it will sync the request context with the headers traceID, spanID and traceFlags.
After this we are good to create tracer and spans as we want.

```
func Tracing(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        traceID, _ := trace.TraceIDFromHex(r.Header["X-B3-Traceid"][0])
        spanID, _ := trace.SpanIDFromHex(r.Header["X-B3-Spanid"][0])
        var traceFlags trace.TraceFlags
        if r.Header["X-B3-Sampled"][0] == "1" {
            traceFlags = trace.FlagsSampled
        }

        spanContext := trace.NewSpanContext(trace.SpanContextConfig{
            TraceID:    traceID,
            SpanID:     spanID,
            TraceFlags: traceFlags,
        })

        ctx := trace.ContextWithSpanContext(r.Context(), spanContext)

        r = r.WithContext(ctx)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```